# How to move select image button forward when selecting one in flutter

Tags: image, flutter

I'm trying to upload multiple image not once, but like this, when user select one image then upload image image will move forward, here is the snap what i'm trying to say

on click on add button an image picker will display

[image]

then after selecting the image this should be like this

[image]

here i'm selecting one image.

```
final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
  File? _image;
  

  Future pickImagefromGallery() async{
    try{
      final image=await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if(image==null) return;

      // final imageTemp=File(image.path);
      final imagePermanent=await saveImagePermantly(image.path);
      setState(() {
        this._image=imagePermanent;
      });
    } on PlatformException catch(e){
      print("Failed to pick an image" + e.toString());
    }
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        child: _image!=null?Image.file(_image!,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.13,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
         ):
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          child: customImageButton(
          context,
          "+",
          (){pickImagefromGallery()})
):}}
```

output:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can put all widgets into a `List` with a `Wrap` as parent.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html

```
List<Widgets> listWidgets = [];

...

//then you can add any widget to list
//first you need to add your button to list
listWidgets.add(Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      child: customImageButton(
      context,
      "+",
      (){pickImagefromGallery()}));

listWidgets.add(Image.file(...)); // this add widget to last position
listWidgets.insert(0, Image.file(...)); // this add to first position like you want
// when you add a widget into list need to do a setState()

// and use Wrap with a list

Wrap(
   children: listWidgets,
)
```

Comment: can u please provide some code, how to add button in a list

Comment: i have updated the code!